# Content security policy preventing googleapis script loading

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I have tried a variety of different content security policies for my Android app but I always get the error:

```html
Refused to load the script 'http://192.168.1.254/oie/mobile-step0.html?originalurl=maps.googleapis.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
                           127.0.0.1:*
                           http://*.itunes.apple.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.maxplatform.com
                           https://*.itunes.apple.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.maxplatform.com
                           ".
```

The full content of my security policy is:

```html
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src *;
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
                           127.0.0.1:*
                           http://*.itunes.apple.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.maxplatform.com
                           https://*.itunes.apple.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.maxplatform.com
                           ;
               style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'
                           127.0.0.1:*
                           http://*.itunes.apple.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.maxplatform.com
                           https://*.itunes.apple.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.maxplatform.com
    ">
```

I am using the cordova whitelist plugin with the following settings in my config.xml:

```html
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
```

The script tag for the google maps api is:

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

I am running on a Samsung Android 4.2 phone.

If I add http://192.168.1.254 to the content security policy it works but surely I shouldn't need that and anyway it is specific to my setup and only appropriate while debugging my Android app through my local network.

I need to find a solution, i.e. a content security policy, that works without the 192.168.1.254 being added.

Comment: Are you using the right cordova version? Android 2.2 is very old and the current version of cordova needs SDK 14, Android 4.x minimum.

Comment: Hi Joerg, that was a typo :) should have been 4.2! I am running Cordova 5.3.3

Comment: How you have added the script tag for google apis?

Comment: Hi rahul, I have added the google apis script tag to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @BillNoble, I don't see what your goal is with this. Can you explain more in your post? and make sure to message me when you do that.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I have added a note to the bottom of my post. Basically I am looking for a content security solution for my Android Cordova app that will work for all users of my app. The solution I mention in the post will only work for me when connected to my local network.

Comment: I'm confuse. Your comments add very little in the way of useful information. I see you have "googlemaps". Is that a goal? If so, you need to say that. I have googlemaps working - with the new security protocol. You have `192.168.1.*` which is a non-routable address, and you have `127.0.0.1` which is `localhost` - both likely used by an emulator (or similar) . You plenty of security. SO, you need to be clear on what you are doing, because I am not going to play 20 questions.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 apologies for the lack of clarity and many thanks for taking a look at this. I am trying to explain as best I know how. Currently, with my Android phone using my local wifi the google maps api only loads if I add the 192.168.1.254 bit to my content security. I want to create a version of the content security tag that doesn't need the 192.168.1.254 bit so that my app can be used by everyone no matter where they are connected to the internet. My app is created using ionic/cordova and is running on a phone not an emulator. Hope this information is sufficient?

Comment: This is what confuses me. I don't see a reason for the *local wifi* or the *local host*. There is no requirement for this - whatsoever. So why are you doing this in the first place? This makes no sense. AND WHAT IS YOU END GOAL? YOU ARE NOT SAYING WHAT IT IS.

Comment: I am testing my app on a phone connected to my laptop by USB cable. The app connects to the internet using my wifi connection. The only way I can get the googleapis script to load is by adding the 192.168.254 to the CSP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96441/discussion-between-jessemonroy650-and-bill-noble).

Comment: Not sure how to chat

Comment: The goal is to have a csp that allows the googleapis script to download without adding the 192.168.1.254 stuff.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the IP? As I have said, I already have examples of Google maps working. FWIW: remove the cable.

Comment: if i remove the IP I get the error shown at the top of my posting. I need it to work with cable connected so I can debug app using Chrome. It works if I completely remove the CSP but Chrome warns that there should be a CSP.

Comment: Okay. I was hoping you've figure this out, but I guess I must spell it out. Your debugger is using local network. You are adding confusion to this by a mental insistence that *phonegap webview* library and *Chrome*  are the same thing. They are not.

Comment: No I dont think they are the same thing. All I am trying to do is have a csp that works without the ip address

Comment: Does this csf tag works for you? 
````html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: http:">
````

Comment: Not sure what a csf tag is @rahul ? That CSP doesn't work for me no.

Comment: Oops! I made a typo there, I meant CSP only. That csp tags load all the script from https and http. Have you tried creating the new project and loading just the maps (use https for script tag)?

Comment: I will try that @rahul. For the moment I just want to create a CSP that let everything through.